# How do I use Transactions API for non paid table booking google action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

So I am making a google action in which user can book a table and I completed making it and gave it for review it got rejected and they said my skill have to use the transaction API for non paid booking table so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning, Jigar! If your action doesn't require or accept payment, you could reframe the marketing into a "reservations" app, where your action asks the following:

1. "What kind of food are you in the mood for?" (User says, "Mexican food")
2. "Ok, I can make a reservation at a nearby Mexican restaurant. To do that, I'll need to know your approximate location. Is that alright?" (see [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Permission) for implementation details)
3. (Hit the Yelp API or Google Maps API to find a list of top rated Mexican restaurants near the user's location.)
4. "Ok, Yelp's top rated Mexican restaurant nearby is Super Awesome Mexican Food on Sixth Street. Would you like to make a reservation?" (user says yes)
5. "How many people are in your party?" (User says, "2")
6. "Ok. A table for two is available at [list like 7 pm, 7:30 pm, 8:00 pm, etc]. Which time would you like to reserve?" (User says, "Seven thirty")
7. "Ok, I'll need an email to finalize your reservation. Which address should I use?"
8. "Ok, your table is reserved, and an email has been sent to your inbox and the restaurant. Please show the email to the host when you arrive. Bon appetit!"

Since you said your app in non paid, this seems like it gets across the same features, without dealing with transactions or money. I'm guessing Google's review team had a problem with the term "booking", which implies money exchanges hands.